# Heroku Spring boot Java app show R14 (Memory quota exceeded) with lightweight heap memory used

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I have an Heroku app, pretty simple with :

- one free dyno
- Heroku postgres
- New relic APM, I'm just using it for ping my app every 15 minuts

The logs show me that my dyno is using too much memory, even if I restart my dyno :

```
2022-04-12T20:37:30.654162+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=598M(116.0%)
2022-04-12T20:37:30.659620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

So I tried to investigate and used jconsole with :

```
heroku java:jconsole
```

with the current result :

[image]

As you can see, my heap memory usage is not so big : only between 100 and 200 MB. Heroku is complaining about 598Mb of memory used.

My database is also pretty lightweight : [image]

What could be the cause ?